# Is it intentional that you can still see the close link on a question deleted by its owner?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

I saw this question: [How does python implement modular exponentiation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116739/how-does-python-implement-modular-exponentiation). It was deleted by its owner, but it is still possible to see the link to cast a close vote.

**Edit**: If you try to close it you get an error message. So its only the link.

Is this intentional, or is it a bug?

Comment: I'm sure it's intentional. You still see the "flag" link, too. Should all of those be removed when the question is deleted?

Comment: It could be regarded as a bug, but the problem a) only affects 10K+ users and b) those that click on a link that clearly isn't going to do anything. So I'd say "don't click the close" link. The effort in removing it probably isn't worth it.

Comment: @Oded I can now vote to close deleted questions. Is this intentional, or is it a bug?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - That would be a bug. The link _should_ be there, but you shouldn't be able to vote to close a deleted question (not that it hurts).

Comment: Cheers @Oded, better remove the status-bydesign then unless you think we should post new bug report?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - A new bug report would be better (the original here was about seeing the link, which _is_ status-bydesign)

Comment: @Oded found [existing report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185913/152859). :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the developers preferred to keep it simple: for deleted question, ordinary (less than 10K rep) members get Not Found page while the OP and high rep members see the question page "as is", with a different background and a message below the question body saying it was deleted, by whom and when.

While this is possible to request whole different design for page showing deleted answer (that will of course contain no Delete/Close/Flag links) I don't think there is point to change the current design.