# Vote to close a deleted question - bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

I just successfully added my Close vote to a question on Stack Overflow that had already been deleted by the author.  The question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310636/what-is-currently-wanted-in-job-market-jobs-c-or-c-and-what-is-the-future).

> [image]

The only purpose I see for such functionality is perhaps to stop someone from escaping the initial surge of wrath from critics, then subsequently undeleting their question.  And that would be a pretty strange thing to guard against.  It seems far more likely that this is an oddity that was overlooked.

So I'm just curious - is voting to close a deleted question a bug, or is it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)?  If by design, what is the rationale behind it?

Comment: Question is now closed, it feels so strange!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yes there are also 2 users with less than 10k that voted to close

Comment: @Jehof strange, how did they manage to do that??

Comment: The plot thickens....

Comment: If you select the "other" off-topic reason then you can also post a comment on the deleted question while you cast your vote.

Comment: @Jeremy nice find! Clever way to post comment on a deleted question.

Comment: @paddy, consider un-accepting the answer below. It's a little funny for this question to appear to be resolved, despite the bug still existing.

Comment: I'm adding [meta-tag:status-completed] because it is currently not possible to vote to close a deleted question (I tried - it gives a red error box).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a bug. I don't understand why this should happen but I assume it is  because of the time it takes for the `close` counter to get updated with the fact that the question was deleted.