# Is it possible to undelete this incorrectly migrated-then-locked post to reveal useful answers?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration, deleted-questions

I wrote a lengthy question last year on SO about matrix multiplication. It was answered well, and it had gotten about 20 upvotes and 3000 views. In January a moderator decided controversially to migrate it to Code Review, despite people thinking it was more appropriate for StackOverflow. Now, just recently, the Code Review moderators have decided that it was off-topic for Code Review and locked it. This caused the answers to be migrated back to StackOverflow, but the question is deleted on SO and I can't undelete it. The upshot is that people can no longer see the useful accepted answer (sigh).

The questions are here:

- StackOverflow (with answers, deleted) [Why is a naïve C++ matrix multiplication 100 times slower than BLAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532169/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas)
- Code Review (no answers, locked) https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20980/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas

Basically, I would like the StackOverflow one undeleted, so people can continue to search for and find Eric Postpischil's very useful answer. I've clicked undelete on the StackOverflow one some time ago and there has been no response. Sigh!

Comment: So the bug is when a migration gets rejected after the original is auto-deleted.

Comment: @Mysticial: Well I can still see the question and answers on the SO version, it is just in the deleted state and I can't undelete it.  When you visit the SO link what do you see?

Comment: The whole question is deleted.

Comment: @Mysticial: Yeah, so the data is still there, but it is only visible to me and I assume moderators?  So I just need a moderator to click undelete on it I guess?

Comment: My guess is: Migrated questions get auto-deleted after a month. Rejecting a migration is supposed to prevent that deletion. But if it's already deleted when the migration is rejected, then it doesn't undelete.

Comment: I can see it too since I'm 10k.

Comment: @Mysticial: Ok well try clicking reopen for me, maybe if 4 people do that it will fix it.

Comment: It has to be a moderator as it was deleted by community... It's worth noting that [Shog9 believes you should be jealous of your site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133694/is-it-possible-weve-got-too-many-stack-exchange-sites-categories/133697#133697)...

Comment: I have a feeling this has been discussed, but why am I able to cast reopen votes on deleted questions? This isn't a bug is it? Because I was just able to vote to reopen this while it was still deleted..

Comment: The question is now open, but deleted. (Huh? [Vote to close a deleted question -- bug?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185913)) As for the cat, I still haven't looked inside the box.

Comment: Ok the vote to reopen has gone through but it is still in deleted state.  MODERATOR PLEASE CLICK UNDELETE ON THIS POST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532169/naive-c-matrix-multiplication-100-times-slower-than-blas

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks - that's what I was looking for. Just posted a bounty on it.

Comment: Fixed now.  Thanks whoever did it.